# Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID

Tags: mysql, innodb

After a management over-sight, the hard disk utilization of the mysql server went to 100%. In panic, I shut down most of the services - including mysqld, which I guess caused this problem. Subsequently, I deleted files to make space. With more than 1GB available, I attempted to start mysqld but it just couldn't start. The errors stated in the log were:

```
[ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
[ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 23 = ['archive/transaction_archive_1.ibd', 'log/transaction_15.ibd']
[ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 123 =
['archive/order_archive_1.ibd', 'log/cart_15.ibd']
[ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 406 = ['archive/pay_archive_8.ibd', 'log/cart_20.ibd']
[ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 419 = ['archive/pay_archive_9.ibd', 'log/cart_64.ibd']
[ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
[ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
[System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

'archive' and 'log' are two separate databases. Setting 'innodb_force_recovery' from 1 to 6 did not help. Any suggestions on how to recover this? The server is running on Linux and MySQL is v8.0.13. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get mysql server to start but I cannot be sure this was the best way.

First, I decided that the 'log' database tables were more important than 'archive' tables. I moved the four affected files - archive/transaction_archive_1.ibd, archive/order_archive_1.ibd, archive/pay_archive_8.ibd, archive/pay_archive_9.ibd) to a temporary location. When I started mysqld, there was a long wait (I think it was performing undos and other stuff) and there were complaints of missing ibd files - which was expected. But the server started nevertheless.

I then backed up the four affected tables of the 'log' database. The affected 'archived' tables were there but was unable to query any data from it ('tablespace missing' error). Next, I shut down mysql and swapped the ibd files - moved the 'archive' ibd files back and removed the 'log' ibd files. The mysqld started with complaints of missing ibd files again. This time, I went to mysql console and dropped the four affected 'log' tables. Then I restored these four tables from the backups I just did a while ago.

Could not be 100% sure no data were lost.

Comment: Any news on how it went after this? Thanks!